# "Friendly" role name since Azure PostgreSQL connection via AD security group role requires the AD group name as the username@pgservername?

Tags: postgresql, azure, role, active-directory

With PostgreSQL's use of the rolename@pgservername and AD auth requiring the security group name as the role name, any user connecting via AD must know their AD security group name.  I'd like to user a friendly group role name like "ProjectXReaders" and have the ADSecurityGroupY role as a member of ProjectXReaders, but since ADSecurityGroupY is already a member of the built-in azure_ad_user group role, I'm not sure the auth and/or permissions will work correctly.  Am I on the right track?  Thanks!